# Error on a Specific Line Number - Android Studio

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio

No matter how I change that specific line, even if I put nothing in it, or making it a comment, or delete the code all together, the error message keeps telling me that this line causes the error. I even tried deleting the class and copying it all into a new one but still same line numebr is an error.

The code with the error line (109) highlighted:

```js
package com.example.president;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Game extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


    private Manager gManager;
    Player p1,p2,p3;
    private ImageView[] hand;
    private ImageView[] curr;
    private ImageView[] next= new ImageView[3];
    private int[] turn = {0, 1, 2};
    private int cthrow;
    public int[] cards =
            {
                    R.drawable.c3,
                    R.drawable.c4,
                    R.drawable.c5,
                    R.drawable.c6,
                    R.drawable.c7,
                    R.drawable.c8,
                    R.drawable.c9,
                    R.drawable.c10,
                    R.drawable.c11,
                    R.drawable.c12,
                    R.drawable.c13,
                    R.drawable.c1,
                    R.drawable.c2,
                    R.drawable.h3,
                    R.drawable.h4,
                    R.drawable.h5,
                    R.drawable.h6,
                    R.drawable.h7,
                    R.drawable.h8,
                    R.drawable.h9,
                    R.drawable.h10,
                    R.drawable.h11,
                    R.drawable.h12,
                    R.drawable.h13,
                    R.drawable.h1,
                    R.drawable.h2,
                    R.drawable.s3,
                    R.drawable.s4,
                    R.drawable.s5,
                    R.drawable.s6,
                    R.drawable.s7,
                    R.drawable.s8,
                    R.drawable.s9,
                    R.drawable.s10,
                    R.drawable.s11,
                    R.drawable.s12,
                    R.drawable.s13,
                    R.drawable.s1,
                    R.drawable.s2,
                    R.drawable.d3,
                    R.drawable.d4,
                    R.drawable.d5,
                    R.drawable.d6,
                    R.drawable.d7,
                    R.drawable.d8,
                    R.drawable.d9,
                    R.drawable.d10,
                    R.drawable.d11,
                    R.drawable.d12,
                    R.drawable.d13,
                    R.drawable.d1,
                    R.drawable.d2,
                    R.drawable.j1,
                    R.drawable.j2
            };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        p1 = new Player("p1");
        p2 = new Player("p2");
        p3 = new Player("p3");

        this.hand = new ImageView[18];
        String str;
        int resId;
        int i;
        for (i=0;i<hand.length;i++)
        {
            str = "card"+i;
            resId = getResources().getIdentifier(str, "id", getPackageName());
            hand[i]= (ImageView)findViewById(resId);
            hand[i].setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        for (i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
            str="board"+i;
            resId = getResources().getIdentifier(str, "id", getPackageName());
            curr[i]= (ImageView)findViewById(resId);
            curr[i].setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        this.gManager = new Manager(this, p1, p2, p3);

        this.gManager.handingDeck(p1, p2, p3);
[[[LINE 109]]]
        startGame(p1, p2, p3);

    }

    public void startGame(Player p1, Player p2, Player p3) {

        Player p=p1;
        int i;
        for (i=0; i < 18; i++) {
            hand[i].setImageResource(cards[p.getHand().get(i).getIndex()]);
        }
        String text = p1.getHand().toString();
        TextView change = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        change.setText(text);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int i, cnum=0, t=0, resId;
        boolean found = false;
        Player p=p1;
        cthrow=1;
        for (i = 0; i < 18 && (!(found)); i++)
        {
            if (v.getId() == hand[i].getId())
            {
                String str="card"+cnum;
                resId=getResources().getIdentifier(str, "id", getPackageName());
                next[turn[t]]= (ImageView)findViewById(resId);
                found=true;
                curr[cthrow].setImageResource(cards[p.getHand().get(i).getIndex()]);
                p.getHand().remove(i);
                next[turn[t]].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                if(cnum<10)
                    cnum=18-cnum;
                else
                    cnum=18-cnum+1;
                cthrow++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the line is even empty.

[image: The error]

Comment: only for curiosity, why you didn't paste your logcat?

Comment: You didn't initialize your **curr**. Try like `this.curr = new ImageView[4];` Change size as your needed

Comment: why should I post it?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman lol you right thanks tho still didn't solve it

Comment: That is expected. Try to initialize with large size and check

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman tried setting it like that - this.curr = new ImageView[1000];
Still same error

Comment: Why not you [**debug**](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) code and check which cause the problem? It's easy to do that rather than asking a silly question. Hope you understand

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman I actually don't know how to debug on Android, maybe it's time to learn lol.
I'll try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments the error happens actually here:

```
HERE>> curr[i]= (ImageView)findViewById(resId);
curr[i].setOnClickListener(this);
```

But it will happen at any line where you use `curr` as it is not initialized.

**For your specific error:**
When an error line do not change even if you intentionally change your code the only plausible answer is only one. The actual running code is an **old** one. So you need to refresh it. How? it depends on where / how you are running it, but a straight forward approach will be to follow this steps incrementally (testing if something changes meanwhile):

- Rebuild your project (using your ide rebuild button or by command line)
- Clean build your project (ide or cmd as above)
- Redeploy your application (in case of an android application 're-install' it on the device where you are testing; emulator or phone)
- Uninstall and delete the currently running application (and repeat point 2 & 3)
- Reboot your test device (emulator / phone and repeat point 2 & 3)
- Reboot your IDE (if you are not sure that all its processes rebooted, reboot your pc)
- Delete any build intermediate / cache file your ide may have stored (and repeat 2 & 3)
- Nothing worked. Attempt different combinations of the above solutions
- If you are here, start thinking about the most dumb stuff and get creative, like:

  - am I installing the app?
  - have I stored the modified files?
  - is the phone connected?
  - am I modifying the files in the right project?
  - ...

Hope this can help

Answer (score 0):

you have initialized array in a wrong manner, by using **new** it will initialize array and create memory for that array.

-- so right way to initialize and add values to array is following.

`public int[] cards = new int[]{ add your Drawbles here };`

Comment: you didn't initialize curr array ..initialize first and then add values to it

Comment: I'm aware of that, did initialize it now

Comment: "Already was notified for that, still didn't solve the error" - as I said earlier